# Sudo apt-get update end with Failed - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates

When I'm trying to update packages using **sudo apt-get update** it ends with this error

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/langdalepl/gvfs-mtp/ubuntu
xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore 
potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user 
configuration details.

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/langdalepl/gvfs-mtp/ubuntu
/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old 
ones used instead.
```

Can anyone help me !
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are running Xenial and the PPA only has files for Precise, Quantal and Raring.

Open Software and Updates, click on the 'Other Software' tab, scroll down to find the PPA you added, then select it and click 'remove'.

When you close software and updates, it will prompt you to update your system. Let it and the error should be gone.

Unfortunately, you cannot use this PPA with your version of Ubuntu.

Rob